# Macros for generation boost::mpl::vector sequence

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

After long time searching how to generate function with variadic argument i found some solution.

```
    #define item(z, n, _) \
    BOOST_PP_EXPR_IF(n, +) BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n) \
    #define add(z, n, _) \
    template inline T add( BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS( BOOST_PP_INC(n), T p) ) \
    { \
        return BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_INC(n), item, ~); \
    } \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(ADD_MAX_ARITY, add, ~)
    #undef item
    #undef add
```

This is macros generate function, like T add(...){ return a+b....;},
and i founded how to do macro recursive expansion. [Macro recursive expansion to a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286950/macro-recursive-expansion-to-a-sequence).
And my question may be possible to mix previous 2 solution to generate something like this?

```
    #define MPL(x) boost::mpl::vector{boost::mpl::char_{x}}
    #define MPL1(x,x1) boost::mpl::vector{boost::mpl::char_{x} ,boost::mpl::char_{x1} }
    ........
    #define MPLN(x,..xn) boost::mpl::vector{boost::mpl::char_{x}...,boost::mpl::char_{xn} }
```

Comment: How interesting i solve this problem write: #define TUPLE_PRINT(n, i, data) data
#define GEN_VECTOR_CHAR(n, i,unused)\
template< BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(i, char T) >\
struct initialize_vector_char<\
BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(i,T)\
BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i)\
BOOST_PP_ENUM(\
BOOST_PP_SUB(MAX_INITIALIZE_VECTOR_SIZE,i), TUPLE_PRINT, 0) >\
{\   \\body here};
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, MAX_INITIALIZE_VECTOR_SIZE, GEN_VECTOR_CHAR, ~) We cannot write variadic #define(automaticaly) but we may write variadic templte or function.