# How do I generate an arbitrarily long list of parameters using macros in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I want a macro that takes any even number of parameters, stitches each pair together, adds some name to the end, let's say `Type`, and then passes them as template arguments to some type, let's call it `CompileTimeList`. So I would give it something like this:

```
MACRO( \
  First,Set, \
  Second,Type, \
  Third,Thing)
```

and it would expand to:

```
CompileTimeList<
  FirstSetType,
  SecondTypeType,
  ThirdThingType>
```

The naive solution would be a variadic recursive template, which is not allowed:

[Can we have recursive macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros)

I could manually hack together a macro using this methodology:

[Macro recursive expansion to a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286950/macro-recursive-expansion-to-a-sequence)

But it would be limited to however many parameters I've defined. I want to be able to expand *any length* of parameters. Is this possible in C++11? I also have Boost 1.55 available, which wasn't mentioned in the other questions.

In order to attempt to implement chris' answer, I've written the following program:

```
  1 #include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
  2
  3 #include <vector>
  4 #include <algorithm>
  5
  6 #define MACRO(...)  \
  7     std::find( \
  8     BOOST_PP_ENUM( \
  9         BOOST_PP_DIV(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 2), \
 10         ENUM_MACRO, \
 11         BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__) \
 12     ) \
 13     )
 14
 15 #define ENUM_MACRO(z, n, data) \
 16     BOOST_PP_CAT( \
 17         BOOST_PP_CAT( \
 18             BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_MUL(n, 2), data), \
 19             BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_MUL(n, 2)), data) \
 20         ), \
 21         Type \
 22     )
 23
 24
 25 typedef int FirstNameType;
 26 typedef std::vector<int>::iterator SecondNameType;
 27 typedef std::vector<int>::iterator ThirdNameType;
 28
 29 int main()
 30 {
 31     std::vector<int>();
 32     auto it = MACRO(First, Name, Second, Name, Third, Name);
 33     return 0;
 34 }
```

Which produces an avalanche of errors relating to the use of commas, starting with:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   src/boost/boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma.hpp:19:27: error:
>   expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token  # define
>   BOOST_PP_COMMA() ,

Comment: I would instead go for `MACRO((First, Set), (Second, Type), (Third, Thing))` and use `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_*`.

Comment: @chris Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. But how do you get around the "reursion isn't allowed" problem?

Comment: @Jason: By recursing anyway: File x.h: `#include "x.h"`...

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure I follow. You mean I should `#include` recursively?

Comment: @Jason, Boost provides utilities for enumerating sequences. Have a look through http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: @Jason: It depends how desperate you are. You can let Boost do the job for you, that's a little more readable.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well I'd prefer to keep it as clean as possible. Boost seems like a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired syntax can be achieved through Boost with a couple macros:

```
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

//The main part is BOOST_PP_ENUM, which loops the number of arguments / 2 times.
//Each loop, ENUM_MACRO is called with the index and a tuple containing the arguments.
//A comma is inserted between all expansions of ENUM_MACRO.
#define MACRO(...)  \
    CompileTimeList< \
    BOOST_PP_ENUM( \
        BOOST_PP_DIV(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 2), \
        ENUM_MACRO, \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
    >

//Since it's called #args/2 times, we multiply the index by 2.
//All it does is concatenate the first in its pair with the second, and then to Type.
#define ENUM_MACRO(z, n, data) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT( \
        BOOST_PP_CAT( \
            BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_MUL(n, 2), data), \
            BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_MUL(n, 2)), data) \
        ), \
        Type \
    )


MACRO(a, b, c, d) //CompileTimeList< abType , cdType >
```

[See it work here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12ebf82754ff7cc7)

While in its current state, this macro will simply ignore the last argument in an odd-numbered list, it is possible to produce an error with a simple `static_assert`, or to do something special with the last argument if so desired.

Comment: I can't get this to run, have to tried running it? I get a bunch of errors that seem to be unrelated... like errors in `BOOST_PP_COMMA()`

Comment: I've modified my answer to include my attempt at implementing your suggestion.

Comment: @Jason It expands to `auto it = std::find( FirstNameType , SecondNameType , ThirdNameType );` just fine (you can use `g++ -E` to see the preprocessed version of your source code). Your problem is that you can't use types as function arguments.

Comment: @Jason, `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` needs to be defined. I'm not sure offhand if there's an easy way to change the code to not need it, but there's also a proper header to include for it (something like `<boost /preprocessor/config/variadics.hpp>`. Now since Coliru doesn't seem to have that header, I'm not sure whether it's included straight from `<boost/preprocessor.hpp>` or not. Anyway, your example [does work with Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b49255e554842767), minus the regular compilation errors of types as arguments.