# C macro expansion not recursive as expected

Tags: c, recursion, macros, c-preprocessor

```c
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define RECURSE() I am recursive, look: _RECURSE()()
#define _RECURSE() RECURSE

I expected:
EVAL1(RECURSE())
=> EVAL1(I am recursive, look: _RECURSE()())
=> EVAL1(I am recursive, look: RECURSE())
=> I am recursive, look: RECURSE()
=> I am recursive, look:I am recursive, look: _RECURSE()()

what I got:
EVAL1(RECURSE())
=> I am recursive, look: RECURSE()
```

Why is RECURSE() not expanded second time when it is passed as an argument to EVAL1?

Another way to achieve what I want is this:

```
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER1(m) m EMPTY()
#define RECURSE() I am recursive, look: DEFER1(_RECURSE)()()
#define _RECURSE() RECURSE

EVAL1(RECURSE())
=> I am recursive, look: I am recursive, look: _RECURSE ()()
```

But I am not sure why this works.

Comment: Because the pre-processor symbol `_RECURSE()` is unknown at the point where `RECURSE()` is expanded. Source code is processed from the top to the bottom.

Comment: @Lundin I think both RECURSE and _RECURSE is defined when executing EVAL1(RECURSE()).

Comment: Okay. I think they are defined at the lines saying `#define`.

Comment: @Lundin No, OP's sample exapansion comes after the three macro definitions.  The sample is `EVAL1(RECURSE())`

Comment: The reason expansion stops is because the preprocessor detects the cycle, and breaks it.  The macro `RECURSE` has already been expanded, so the next instance of `RECURSE` that appears in the expansion is left untouched.  You can see the same thing by skipping `EVAL1` and just doing `RECURSE()`, which will expand to `I am recursive, look: RECURSE()`

Comment: @Lundin OP's comment "I think both `RECURSE` and `_RECURSE` is defined when executing `EVAL1(RECURSE())`." is ambiguously worded, but OP doesn't mean the point of definition is when expanding `EVAL1(RECURSE())`, as you took it, but rather OP means they are defined by the time expansion reaches that point.

Answer (score 4):

The C preprocessor does not allow recursion. More precisely, while the preprocessor is expanding macros, it remembers which macros it's expanding. If it finds one of the macros that are currently being expanded, it leaves it unchanged.

In your example, the evaluation chain is:

- `EVAL1(RECURSE())`
- expanding `EVAL1`: `RECURSE()`
- expanding `EVAL1`, `RECURSE`: `I am recursive, look: _RECURSE()()`
- expanding `EVAL1`, `_RECURSE`, `RECURSE`: `I am recursive, look: RECURSE()`
- nothing left to expand, done.

Forbidding recursion lets you wrap a function with a macro that has the same name. For example:

```c
#define foo(x, y) (printf("DEBUG: foo was called in %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__), foo(x, y))
```

Forbidding recursion also guarantees that the compilation will terminate. (This is actually not true: you can get infinite recursion through `#include` directives. But it takes more work than a simple recursive `#define`. Also termination doesn't necessarily mean *quick* termination: it's possible to build preprocessor expansions that only terminate after a very long time.)

Comment: #define DEFER1(m) m EMPTY()
#define RECURSE() I am recursive, look: DEFER1(_RECURSE)()() How do you expand when RECURSE is defined like this?

Comment: Assuming also `#define EMPTY()` and `#define _RECURSE() RECURSE`: `RECURSE()` → `I am recursive, look: DEFER1(_RECURSE)()()` → `I am recursive, look: _RECURSE()() EMPTY()` → `I am recursive, look: RECURSE() EMPTY()` → `I am recursive, look: RECURSE()`

Comment: Result is : I am recursive, look: I am recursive, look: _RECURSE ()(). I have edit my question so you can try it out.

Comment: @cjkkkk: Your updated example expands `RECURSE` twice because macro processing replaces the arguments to a function-like macro before replacing the function-like macro itself, and, after replacing the function-like macro, it rescans for further macros. That rescan suppresses the macro just replaced (the outer function-like macro) but not the macros that were replaced in the arguments. So this is not recursive, just iterative in that the arguments get macro-replaced (once), and, later, the result of replacement gets macro-replaced (once).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, can you post an answer to elaborate the process of how rescan suppresses some macro?

Comment: There is [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/975097) that allows recursion in C preprocessor macros. Some C++ compilers also support recursion with [\_\_VA_OPT\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166178/recursive-macros-via-va-opt/67878835#67878835).