# Foreach macro on macros arguments

Tags: c++, c, macros, foreach

I wonder if it is possible to write a macro foreach on macros arguments. Here is what want to do:

```
#define PRINT(a) printf(#a": %d", a)
#define PRINT_ALL(...) ? ? ? THE PROBLEM ? ? ?
```

And possible usage:

```
int a = 1, b = 3, d = 0;
PRINT_ALL(a,b,d);
```

Here is what I achieved so far

```
#define FIRST_ARG(arg,...) arg
#define AFTER_FIRST_ARG(arg,...) , ##__VA_ARGS__     
#define PRINT(a) printf(#a": %d", a)
#define PRINT_ALL PRINT(FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__)); PRINT_ALL(AFTER_FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__))
```

This is a recursive macro, which is illegal. And another problem with that is `stop condition` of recursion.

Comment: ## in AFTER_FIRST_ARG is a gnu compiler extension of C

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824639/variadic-recursive-preprocessor-macros-is-it-possible

Comment: you can solve this problem in c++ using the comma operator too, in a nicer way.

Comment: @Johannes: Not including the stringized variable names (or expressions, or ...) though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are accepting that the preprocessor has VA_ARGS (in C99, but not in the current C++ standard) you can go with [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for.html). It has exactly what you are asking for: P99_FOR. It works without the crude `()()()` syntax from BOOST. The interface is just

```
P99_FOR(NAME, N, OP, FUNC,...)
```

and you can use it with something like

```
#define P00_SEP(NAME, I, REC, RES) REC; RES
#define P00_VASSIGN(NAME, X, I) X = (NAME)[I]
#define MYASSIGN(NAME, ...) P99_FOR(NAME, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_SEP, P00_VASSIGN, __VA_ARGS__)

MYASSIGN(A, toto, tutu);
```

Comment: Oh, that crude `,,,` syntax ;)

Comment: @Georg :) While the definition of macros might sometimes look strange the usage of macros should just follow usual conventions of the language(s), I think.

Comment: Just kidding, couldn't resist to comment on the Boost pun :) I guess i got used to it though.

Comment: The example is actually not so clear. Could you change it so as to perform the printf's OP asked for?

Answer (score 70):

Yes, recursive macros are possible in C using a fancy workaround. The end goal is to create a `MAP` macro which works like this:

```
#define PRINT(a) printf(#a": %d", a)
MAP(PRINT, a, b, c) /* Apply PRINT to a, b, and c */
```

### Basic Recursion

First, we need a technique for emitting something that looks like a macro
call, but isn't yet:

```
#define MAP_OUT
```

Imagine we have the following macros:

```
#define A(x) x B MAP_OUT (x)
#define B(x) x A MAP_OUT (x)
```

Evaluating the macro `A (blah)` produces the output text:

```
blah B (blah)
```

The preprocessor doesn't see any recursion, since the `B (blah)` call is
just plain text at this point, and `B` isn't even the name of the current
macro. Feeding this text back into the preprocessor expands the call,
producing the output:

```
blah blah A (blah)
```

Evaluating the output a third time expands the `A (blah)` macro, carrying
the recursion full-circle. The recursion continues as long as the caller
continues to feed the output text back into the preprocessor.

To perform these repeated evaluations, the following `EVAL` macro passes
its arguments down a tree of macro calls:

```
#define EVAL0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL0 (EVAL0 (EVAL0 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1 (EVAL1 (EVAL1 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL2 (EVAL2 (EVAL2 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL3 (EVAL3 (EVAL3 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL4 (EVAL4 (EVAL4 (__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Each level multiplies the effort of the level before, evaluating the input
365 times in total. In other words, calling `EVAL (A (blah))` would
produce 365 copies of the word `blah`, followed by a final un-evaluated `B (blah)`. This provides the basic framework for recursion, at least within a
certain stack depth.

### End Detection

The next challenge is to stop the recursion when it reaches the end of the
list.

The basic idea is to emit the following macro name instead of the normal
recursive macro when the time comes to quit:

```
#define MAP_END(...)
```

Evaluating this macro does nothing, which ends the recursion.

To actually select between the two macros, the following `MAP_NEXT`
macro compares a single list item against the special end-of-list marker
`()`. The macro returns `MAP_END` if the item matches, or the `next`
parameter if the item is anything else:

```
#define MAP_GET_END() 0, MAP_END
#define MAP_NEXT0(item, next, ...) next MAP_OUT
#define MAP_NEXT1(item, next) MAP_NEXT0 (item, next, 0)
#define MAP_NEXT(item, next)  MAP_NEXT1 (MAP_GET_END item, next)
```

This macro works by placing the item next to the `MAP_GET_END` macro. If
doing that forms a macro call, everything moves over by a slot in the
`MAP_NEXT0` parameter list, changing the output. The `MAP_OUT` trick
prevents the preprocessor from evaluating the final result.

### Putting it All Together

With these pieces in place, it is now possible to implement useful versions
of the `A` and `B` macros from the example above:

```
#define MAP0(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT (peek, MAP1) (f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)
#define MAP1(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT (peek, MAP0) (f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)
```

These macros apply the operation `f` to the current list item `x`. They then
examine the next list item, `peek`, to see if they should continue or not.

The final step is to tie everything together in a top-level `MAP` macro:

```
#define MAP(f, ...) EVAL (MAP1 (f, __VA_ARGS__, (), 0))
```

This macro places a `()` marker on the end of the list, as well as an extra
`0` for ANSI compliance (otherwise, the last iteration would have an illegal
0-length list). It then passes the whole thing through `EVAL` and
returns the result.

I have uploaded this code as a [library on github](https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro) for your convenience.

Comment: Very nice. But is it possible to pass some value along with __VA_ARGS__ to target function? I managed to add 1 param, but when I try to pack a few params within that one, I stuck. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8622a9a5fb7d2ba5

Comment: For the record, for this to work with VS2015 in my setup I had to:
`#define MAP_NEXT1(item, next) EVAL0(MAP_NEXT0 (item, next, 0))`

Comment: This has been very useful for me; I have a related (follow-up) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6707148/1593077).

Comment: This works wonderful, except when you get an error inside the macro expansion and you have to scroll up forever to skip all the infos backtracking it through all the EVAL expansions.

Comment: Where did the number 365 come from?

Comment: 365 is because we have 5 levels, where each level expands its input 3 times. So, 1+(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1) = 365. There is a chart at the bottom the github readme showing other possible combinations.

Comment: Very nicely done. I prefer this solution to the P99 lib in the accepted answer, because it's a simple and short header with no dependencies.

Comment: How can I make this work with no values like that: `MAP(f)` so that the output is just nothing?

Answer (score 14):

Using `PPNARG`, I wrote a set of macros to apply a macro to each argument in a macro. I call it a variadic X-macro.

```
/*
 * The PP_NARG macro evaluates to the number of arguments that have been
 * passed to it.
 *
 * Laurent Deniau, "__VA_NARG__," 17 January 2006, <comp.std.c> (29 November 2007).
 */
#define PP_NARG(...)    PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,PP_RSEQ_N())
#define PP_NARG_(...)   PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)

#define PP_ARG_N( \
        _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10,  \
        _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
        _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
        _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
        _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
        _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
        _61,_62,_63,N,...) N

#define PP_RSEQ_N() \
        63,62,61,60,                   \
        59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
        49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
        39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
        29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
        19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
        9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

`PPNARG` lets us get a count of how many arguments there are. Then we append that number to the macro name and call it with the original arguments.

```
/* need extra level to force extra eval */
#define Paste(a,b) a ## b
#define XPASTE(a,b) Paste(a,b)


/* APPLYXn variadic X-Macro by M Joshua Ryan      */
/* Free for all uses. Don't be a jerk.            */
/* I got bored after typing 15 of these.          */
/* You could keep going upto 64 (PPNARG's limit). */
#define APPLYX1(a)           X(a)
#define APPLYX2(a,b)         X(a) X(b)
#define APPLYX3(a,b,c)       X(a) X(b) X(c)
#define APPLYX4(a,b,c,d)     X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d)
#define APPLYX5(a,b,c,d,e)   X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e)
#define APPLYX6(a,b,c,d,e,f) X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f)
#define APPLYX7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g)
#define APPLYX8(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h)
#define APPLYX9(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i)
#define APPLYX10(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j)
#define APPLYX11(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j) X(k)
#define APPLYX12(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j) X(k) X(l)
#define APPLYX13(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j) X(k) X(l) X(m)
#define APPLYX14(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j) X(k) X(l) X(m) X(n)
#define APPLYX15(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o) \
    X(a) X(b) X(c) X(d) X(e) X(f) X(g) X(h) X(i) X(j) X(k) X(l) X(m) X(n) X(o)
#define APPLYX_(M, ...) M(__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLYXn(...) APPLYX_(XPASTE(APPLYX, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)
```

And here are some examples with the output from `gcc -E` in comments.

```
/* Example */
#define X(a) #a,
char *list[] = {
    APPLYXn(sugar,coffee,drink,smoke)
};
#undef X

/* Produces (gcc -E)
char *list[] = {
    "sugar", "coffee", "drink", "smoke",
};
 */


#define c1(a) case a:
#define c2(a,b)     c1(a) c1(b)
#define c3(a,b,c)   c1(a) c2(b,c)
#define c4(a,b,c,d) c1(a) c3(b,c,d)
#define c_(M, ...) M(__VA_ARGS__)
#define cases(...) c_(XPASTE(c, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)


//cases(3,4,5,6,7)
//produces
//case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6:


#define r_(a,b) range(a,b)
#define range(a,b) a,r_(a+1,b-1)
//range(3,4)

#define ps1(a) O ## a ();
#define ps2(a,b)     ps1(a) ps1(b)
#define ps3(a,b,c)   ps1(a) ps2(b,c)
#define ps4(a,b,c,d) ps1(a) ps3(b,c,d)
#define ps_(M, ...) M(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ps(...)     ps_(XPASTE(ps, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)

//ps(dup,add,sub)
```

This last was the motive for the whole thing. But it didn't turn out to be very useful.

---

*Edit: many years later...*

If we take a step back and reimagine the goal "apply a macro to each argument of a macro", this ia almost the same thing as an X-Macro. And I think an X-Macro can be made to do roughly the same job with a slight difference in syntax.

```
#define EACH_THING(X) \
  X(Thing1) \
  X(Thing2) \
  X(OtherThing) \
/**/
```

Then you can write a macro that deals with each thing individually and by invoking the *`EACH_*`* with the name of the macro to use.

```
#define BareWord_comma(X) X ,
#define String_comma(X) #X ,

enum{ EACH_THING( BareWord_comma ) NUM_THINGS };
char*names[]={ EACH_THING( String_comma ) NULL };
```

Here the list of things isn't the argument list to a macro, but a sequence of macro invocations in the body of a macro. The important parts are all here, though: separating the list of things from the transformation to apply to each one.

Comment: I'm still tickled by my *youthful/arrogant* "copyright notice". :)

Comment: By virtue of posting to StackOverflow, this code is public domain, correct? ... it seems there's an automatic Creative Commons license, according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Comment: p.s, in my youthful/arrogant days, I used http://www.wtfpl.net/about/. LawyerCats get all bent out of shape over that b/c it doesn't explicitly say you can copy the code.

Comment: Technically, it's [CC by SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/). Almost the same as PD but requiring attribution.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ without extensions you could go for [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor) and it's sequences:

```
PRINT_ALL((a)(b)(c));
```

By using `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH()` on the sequence you can iterate it and easily generate code that prints them.

Untested straight-forward sample:

```
#define DO_PRINT(elem) std::cout << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem) << "=" << (elem) << "\n";
#define PRINT_ALL(seq) { BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DO_PRINT, _, seq) }
```

Comment: GCC decides that `DO_PRINT` both exists and doesn't, and either way it's not happy: `macro "DO_PRINT" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1` ... `error: ‘DO_PRINT’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: I found that `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(macro, data, seq)` calls `macro(index, data, seq[index-2])` where `index` is an index that starts at 2 for some reason (tested with gcc 8.1.0) and `seq[index-2]` is an element of the sequence. The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) just describes the first parameter as "the next available [BOOST_PP_FOR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/for.html) repetition".

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I thought I'd tack on a solution I came up with to use Boost.Preprocessor without the ugly `(a)(b)` syntax.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\preprocessor.hpp>

#define _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR1(_var) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(_var) " = " << (_var) << std::endl
#define _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR2(r, d, _var) << _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR1(_var) 
#define _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR_SEQ(vseq) _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR1(BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(vseq)) \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(_PPSTUFF_OUTVAR2,,BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(vseq)) 
#define OUTVAR(...) _PPSTUFF_OUTVAR_SEQ(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Usage:

```
int a = 3;
char b[] = "foo";

std::cout << OUTVAR(a);

// Expands to: 
//
// std::cout << "a" " = " << (a ) << std::endl  ;
//
// Output:
//
// a = 3

std::cout << OUTVAR(a, b);

// Expands to: 
//
// std::cout << "a" " = " << (a ) << std::endl << "b" " = " << (b) << std::endl  ;
//
// Output:
//
// a = 3
// b = foo
```

Nice and clean.

Of course you can replace the `std::endl` with a comma or something if you want it all on one line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Boost.PP (after adding [Boost](https://www.boost.org/)'s `boost` folder to your list of include directories) to get macros for this. Here's an example (tested with GCC 8.1.0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define WRITER(number,middle,elem) std::cout << \
    number << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(middle) << elem << "\n";
#define PRINT_ALL(...) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(WRITER, =>, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PRINT_ALL(INT_MAX, 123, "Hello, world!");
}
```

**Output:**

```
2=>2147483647
3=>123
4=>Hello, world!
```

The `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)` part converts the variable-argument list to Boost's traditional way of expressing multiple arguments as a single argument, which looks like this: `(item1)(item2)(item3)`.

Not sure why it starts numbering the arguments at two. The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) just describes the first parameter as "the next available [BOOST_PP_FOR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/for.html) repetition".

Here's another example that defines an `enum` with the ability to write it as a string to an `ostream`, which also enables Boost's `lexical_cast<string>`:

```
#define ENUM_WITH_TO_STRING(ENUMTYPE, ...)                   \
    enum ENUMTYPE {                                          \
        __VA_ARGS__                                          \
    };                                                       \
    inline const char* to_string(ENUMTYPE value) {           \
        switch (value) {                                     \
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(_ENUM_TO_STRING_CASE, _,   \
               BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))        \
            default: return nullptr;                         \
        }                                                    \
    }                                                        \
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ENUMTYPE v)\
        { return os << to_string(v); }
#define _ENUM_TO_STRING_CASE(_,__,elem)                      \
    case elem: return BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem);

ENUM_WITH_TO_STRING(Color, Red, Green, Blue)

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << Red << Green << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<string>(Blue) << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
RedGreen
Blue
```

Comment: Can you clarify--does BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH and BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ work only with a non-standard pre-processor?

Comment: @SwissFrank I don't know for sure, but my guess is that BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ, `...` and `__VA_ARGS__` are pretty standard. Boost is known for its compatibility with many compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is not powerful enough to do stuff like this. However, you don't really need the preprocessor that badly. If all you want to do is to dump variable names and their values in a convenient manner. You could have two simple macros:

```
#define PRINT(x) \
{ \
    std::ostringstream stream; \
    stream << x; \
    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl; \
}

#define VAR(v) #v << ": " << v << ", "
```

You could then almost use your intended usage:

```
int a = 1, b = 3, d = 0;
PRINT(VAR(a) << VAR(b) << VAR(d))
```

This prints

```
a: 1, b: 3, d: 0,
```

There are a lot of ways to make this more powerful, but this works, allows you to print non-integer values nicely and it's a rather simple solution.

Comment: The PP is powerful enough, e.g. by using Boost.PP sequences in C++.

Comment: Printing variable names is just a part of what I want to do. I was rather thinking about general idea if it possible to create such macro. It might be useful for different reasons: creating number of let say exception classes, or creating number of variables and then initialize them. There is plenty of possibilities.