# Why won't my little lisp QUOTE?

Tags: c, programming-languages, lisp, interpreter, quote

I've been writing up a micro-mini-lisp based on the encoding in [minilisp](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/minilisp), the [McCarthy paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html) (as emended by the [Roots of Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html)), and using a (possibly objectionable) style based on the [J Incunabulum](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum). And using the `PP_NARG` macro from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722112/733077). I was also motivated by my previous project, a [codegolf'ed lambda calculus interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/284/write-an-interpreter-for-the-untyped-lambda-calculus/3290#3290) which I later discovered to be eerily similar to the [1999 ioccc Lisp interpreter](http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c), particularly in the use of *cursors* rather than *pointers* to refer to memory addresses.

It mostly seems to work, including the reader code. But, although `eval(ATOM(QUOTE X))` is correctly yielding `T`, and `eval(ATOM(QUOTE(X Y Z)))` is correctly yielding `NIL`, and `eval(QUOTE X)` yields `X`, and `eval(QUOTE(X Y Z))` yields `(X Y Z)`; the weird result is `eval(QUOTE(ATOM(QUOTE X)))` yields `ATOM`, not the full sub-expression `ATOM(QUOTE X)`.

I suppose it's a long-shot, and I didn't exactly make it easy, but can anyone help me figure out where it's going wrong with the quoting?

By the way, unlike my description above, the interpreter is limited to single-character tokens, so `QUOTE` is `Q` and `ATOM` is `A`. ([github](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c))

```
/*cf.
http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c
http://leon.bottou.org/projects/minilisp
http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum
http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html
http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/284/write-an-interpreter-for-the-untyped-lambda-calculus/3290#3290
 */
#include<assert.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"ppnarg.h"
#define R return
int*m,*n,msz;
tag(x){R x&3;}
val(x){R x>>2;}
#define ALPHA 'T'
#define NIL   (0)
#define T atom(ALPHA)
atom(x){R((x-ALPHA)<<2)|1;}
number(x){R(x<<2)|3;}
listp(x){R tag(x)==0;}
atomp(x){R tag(x)==1;}
objectp(x){R tag(x)==2;}
numberp(x){R tag(x)==3;}
consp(x){R x&&listp(x);}
car(x){R consp(x)?val(x)[m]:0;}
cdr(x){R consp(x)?val(x)[m+1]:0;}
caar(x){R car(car(x));}
cadr(x){R car(cdr(x));}
cadar(x){R car(cdr(car(x)));}
caddr(x){R car(cdr(cdr(x)));}
caddar(x){R car(cdr(cdr(car(x))));}
cons(x,y){int z;R z=n-m,*n++=x,*n++=y,z<<2;}
rplaca(x,y){R consp(x)?val(x)[m]=y:0;}
rplacd(x,y){R consp(x)?val(x)[m+1]=y:0;}
eq(x,y){R atomp(x)&&atomp(y)?x==y:0;}
ff(x){R atomp(x)?x:ff(car(x));}
subst(x,y,z){R atomp(z)?(eq(z,y)?x:z):
        cons(subst(x,y,car(z)),subst(x,y,cdr(z)));}
equal(x,y){R(atomp(x)&&atomp(y)&&eq(x,y))
    ||(consp(x)&&consp(y)&&equal(car(x),car(y))&&equal(cdr(x),cdr(y)));}
null(x){R listp(x)&&(val(x)==0);}
lista(int c,int*a){int z=NIL;for(;c;)z=cons(a[--c],z);R z;}
listn(int c,...){va_list a;int*z=n;
    va_start(a,c);for(;c--;)*n++=va_arg(a,int);va_end(a);
    c=n-z;R lista(c,z);}
#define list(...) listn(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)
append(x,y){R null(x)?y:cons(car(x),append(cdr(x),y));}
among(x,y){R !null(y)&&equal(x,car(y))||among(x,cdr(y));}
pair(x,y){R null(x)&&null(y)?NIL:
    consp(x)&&consp(y)?cons(list(car(x),car(y)),pair(cdr(x),cdr(y))):0;}
assoc(x,y){R eq(caar(y),x)?cadar(y):assoc(x,cdr(y));}
sub2(x,z){R null(x)?z:eq(caar(x),z)?cadar(x):sub2(cdr(x),z);}
sublis(x,y){R atom(y)?sub2(x,y):cons(sublis(x,car(y)),sublis(x,cdr(y)));}
apply(f,args){R eval(cons(f,appq(args)),NIL);}
appq(m){R null(m)?NIL:cons(list(atom('Q'),car(m)),appq(cdr(m)));}
eval(e,a){R numberp(e)?e:
    atomp(e)?assoc(e,a):
    atomp(car(e))?(
    /*QUOTE*/      eq(car(e),atom('Q'))?cadr(e):
    /*ATOM*/       eq(car(e),atom('A'))?atomp(eval(cadr(e),a)):
    /*EQ*/         eq(car(e),atom('E'))?eval(cadr(e),a)==eval(caddr(e),a):
    /*COND*/       eq(car(e),atom('D'))?evcon(cdr(e),a):
    /*CAR*/        eq(car(e),atom('H'))?car(eval(cadr(e),a)):
    /*CDR*/        eq(car(e),atom('R'))?cdr(eval(cadr(e),a)):
    /*CONS*/       eq(car(e),atom('C'))?cons(eval(cadr(e),a),eval(caddr(e),a)):
        //eval(cons(assoc(car(e),a),evlis(cdr(e),a)),a) ):/*cf. Roots of Lisp*/
        eval(cons(assoc(car(e),a),cdr(e)),a) ):
    eq(caar(e),atom('M'))?          /*LABEL*/
        eval(cons(caddar(e),cdr(e)),cons(list(cadar(e),car(e)),a)):
    eq(caar(e),atom('L'))?          /*LAMBDA*/
        eval(caddar(e),append(pair(cadar(e),evlis(cdr(e),a)),a)):0;}
evcon(c,a){R eval(caar(c),a)?eval(cadar(c),a):evcon(cdr(c),a);}
evlis(m,a){R null(m)?NIL:cons(eval(car(m),a),evlis(cdr(m),a));}
maplist(x,f){R null(x)?NIL:cons(apply(f,x),maplist(cdr(x),f));}

prn(x){atomp(x)?printf("'%c' ",val(x)+ALPHA):
    numberp(x)?printf("%d ",val(x)):
    objectp(x)?printf("OBJ %d ",val(x)):
    consp(x)?printf("( "),prn(car(x)),prn(cdr(x)),printf(") "):
    0//printf("NIL ")
    ;}

#define LPAR '('
#define RPAR ')'
rd(char **p){int t,u,v,z;
    if(!(**p))R 0;
    if(**p==' ')R ++(*p),rd(p);
    if(**p==RPAR)R ++(*p),atom(RPAR);
    if(**p==LPAR){++(*p);
        z=NIL;u=rd(p);z=cons(u,z);
        while(u=rd(p),!eq(u,atom(RPAR)))
            //u=cons(u,NIL),
            z=append(z,u);
        R z;}
    if(**p>='0'&&**p<='9')R ++(*p),number(*((*p)-1)-'0');
    R ++(*p),atom(*((*p)-1));}

void fix(x){signal(SIGSEGV,fix);sbrk(msz);msz*=2;}
int main(){
    assert((-1>>1)==-1); /*right-shift must be sign-preserving*/
    n=m=sbrk(sizeof(int)*(msz=getpagesize()));*n++=0;*n++=0;
    //signal(SIGSEGV,fix); /*might let it run longer, obscures problems*/
    char *s="(Q (A (Q X)))";
    char *p=s;
    int a=rd(&p);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    int x,y;
    x = a;
    y = NIL;

    prn(x);
    x = eval(x,y);
    printf("\nEVAL\n");

    printf("x: %d\n", x);
    printf("0: %o\n", x);
    printf("0x: %x\n", x);
    printf("tag(x): %d\n",tag(x));
    printf("val(x): %d\n",val(x));
    printf("car(x): %d\n",car(x));
    printf("cdr(x): %d\n",cdr(x));
    prn(x);

    R 0;
}
```

Here's the same code processed by `indent`.

```
/*cf.
http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c
http://leon.bottou.org/projects/minilisp
http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum
http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html
http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html
 */
#include<assert.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"ppnarg.h"
#define R return
int *m, *n, msz;
tag (x)
{
  R x & 3;
}

val (x)
{
  R x >> 2;
}

#define ALPHA 'T'
#define NIL   (0)
#define T atom(ALPHA)
atom (x)
{
  R ((x - ALPHA) << 2) | 1;
}

number (x)
{
  R (x << 2) | 3;
}

listp (x)
{
  R tag (x) == 0;
}

atomp (x)
{
  R tag (x) == 1;
}

objectp (x)
{
  R tag (x) == 2;
}

numberp (x)
{
  R tag (x) == 3;
}

consp (x)
{
  R x && listp (x);
}

car (x)
{
  R consp (x) ? val (x)[m] : 0;
}

cdr (x)
{
  R consp (x) ? val (x)[m + 1] : 0;
}

caar (x)
{
  R car (car (x));
}

cadr (x)
{
  R car (cdr (x));
}

cadar (x)
{
  R car (cdr (car (x)));
}

caddr (x)
{
  R car (cdr (cdr (x)));
}

caddar (x)
{
  R car (cdr (cdr (car (x))));
}

cons (x, y)
{
  int z;
  R z = n - m, *n++ = x, *n++ = y, z << 2;
}

rplaca (x, y)
{
  R consp (x) ? val (x)[m] = y : 0;
}

rplacd (x, y)
{
  R consp (x) ? val (x)[m + 1] = y : 0;
}

eq (x, y)
{
  R atomp (x) && atomp (y) ? x == y : 0;
}

ff (x)
{
  R atomp (x) ? x : ff (car (x));
}

subst (x, y, z)
{
  R atomp (z) ? (eq (z, y) ? x : z) :
    cons (subst (x, y, car (z)), subst (x, y, cdr (z)));
}

equal (x, y)
{
  R (atomp (x) && atomp (y) && eq (x, y))
    || (consp (x) && consp (y) && equal (car (x), car (y))
    && equal (cdr (x), cdr (y)));
}

null (x)
{
  R listp (x) && (val (x) == 0);
}

lista (int c, int *a)
{
  int z = NIL;
  for (; c;)
    z = cons (a[--c], z);
  R z;
}

listn (int c, ...)
{
  va_list a;
  int *z = n;
  va_start (a, c);
  for (; c--;)
    *n++ = va_arg (a, int);
  va_end (a);
  c = n - z;
  R lista (c, z);
}

#define list(...) listn(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)
append (x, y)
{
  R null (x) ? y : cons (car (x), append (cdr (x), y));
}

among (x, y)
{
  R ! null (y) && equal (x, car (y)) || among (x, cdr (y));
}

pair (x, y)
{
  R null (x) && null (y) ? NIL :
    consp (x)
    && consp (y) ? cons (list (car (x), car (y)),
             pair (cdr (x), cdr (y))) : 0;
}

assoc (x, y)
{
  R eq (caar (y), x) ? cadar (y) : assoc (x, cdr (y));
}

sub2 (x, z)
{
  R null (x) ? z : eq (caar (x), z) ? cadar (x) : sub2 (cdr (x), z);
}

sublis (x, y)
{
  R atom (y) ? sub2 (x, y) : cons (sublis (x, car (y)), sublis (x, cdr (y)));
}

apply (f, args)
{
  R eval (cons (f, appq (args)), NIL);
}

appq (m)
{
  R null (m) ? NIL : cons (list (atom ('Q'), car (m)), appq (cdr (m)));
}

eval (e, a)
{
  R numberp (e) ? e :
    atomp (e) ? assoc (e, a) :
    atomp (car (e)) ? ( /*QUOTE*/ eq (car (e), atom ('Q')) ? cadr (e) :
               /*ATOM*/ eq (car (e),
                    atom ('A')) ? atomp (eval (cadr (e),
                                   a)) : /*EQ*/
               eq (car (e), atom ('E')) ? eval (cadr (e),
                            a) == eval (caddr (e),
                                    a) :
               /*COND*/ eq (car (e), atom ('D')) ? evcon (cdr (e),
                                  a) : /*CAR*/
               eq (car (e),
               atom ('H')) ? car (eval (cadr (e),
                            a)) : /*CDR*/ eq (car (e),
                                      atom
                                      ('R')) ?
               cdr (eval (cadr (e), a)) : /*CONS*/ eq (car (e),
                                   atom ('C')) ?
               cons (eval (cadr (e), a), eval (caddr (e), a)) :
               //eval(cons(assoc(car(e),a),evlis(cdr(e),a)),a) ):/*cf. Roots of Lisp*/
               eval (cons (assoc (car (e), a), cdr (e)), a)) :
    eq (caar (e), atom ('M')) ? /*LABEL*/
    eval (cons (caddar (e), cdr (e)), cons (list (cadar (e), car (e)), a)) :
    eq (caar (e), atom ('L')) ? /*LAMBDA*/
    eval (caddar (e), append (pair (cadar (e), evlis (cdr (e), a)), a)) : 0;
}

evcon (c, a)
{
  R eval (caar (c), a) ? eval (cadar (c), a) : evcon (cdr (c), a);
}

evlis (m, a)
{
  R null (m) ? NIL : cons (eval (car (m), a), evlis (cdr (m), a));
}

maplist (x, f)
{
  R null (x) ? NIL : cons (apply (f, x), maplist (cdr (x), f));
}

prn (x)
{
  atomp (x) ? printf ("'%c' ", val (x) + ALPHA) : numberp (x) ? printf ("%d ", val (x)) : objectp (x) ? printf ("OBJ %d ", val (x)) : consp (x) ? printf ("( "), prn (car (x)), prn (cdr (x)), printf (") ") : 0    //printf("NIL ")
    ;
}

#define LPAR '('
#define RPAR ')'
rd (char **p)
{
  int t, u, v, z;
  if (!(**p))
    R 0;
  if (**p == ' ')
    R++ (*p), rd (p);
  if (**p == RPAR)
    R++ (*p), atom (RPAR);
  if (**p == LPAR)
    {
      ++(*p);
      z = NIL;
      u = rd (p);
      z = cons (u, z);
      while (u = rd (p), !eq (u, atom (RPAR)))
    //u=cons(u,NIL),
    z = append (z, u);
      R z;
    }
  if (**p >= '0' && **p <= '9')
    R++ (*p), number (*((*p) - 1) - '0');
  R++ (*p), atom (*((*p) - 1));
}

void
fix (x)
{
  signal (SIGSEGV, fix);
  sbrk (msz);
  msz *= 2;
}

int
main ()
{
  assert ((-1 >> 1) == -1); /*right-shift must be sign-preserving */
  n = m = sbrk (sizeof (int) * (msz = getpagesize ()));
  *n++ = 0;
  *n++ = 0;
  //signal(SIGSEGV,fix); /*might let it run longer, obscures problems*/
  char *s = "(Q (A (Q X)))";
  char *p = s;
  int a = rd (&p);
  printf ("%s\n", s);

  int x, y;
  x = a;
  y = NIL;

  prn (x);
  x = eval (x, y);
  printf ("\nEVAL\n");

  printf ("x: %d\n", x);
  printf ("0: %o\n", x);
  printf ("0x: %x\n", x);
  printf ("tag(x): %d\n", tag (x));
  printf ("val(x): %d\n", val (x));
  printf ("car(x): %d\n", car (x));
  printf ("cdr(x): %d\n", cdr (x));
  prn (x);

  R 0;
}
```

Here's the guts of `main` again, the testing portion.

```
    char *s="(Q (A (Q X)))";
    char *p=s;
    int a=rd(&p);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    int x,y;
    x = a;
    y = NIL;

    prn(x);
    x = eval(x,y);
    printf("\nEVAL\n");

    printf("x: %d\n", x);
    printf("0: %o\n", x);
    printf("0x: %x\n", x);
    printf("tag(x): %d\n",tag(x));
    printf("val(x): %d\n",val(x));
    printf("car(x): %d\n",car(x));
    printf("cdr(x): %d\n",cdr(x));
    prn(x);
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
(Q (A (Q X)))
( 'Q' ( 'A' ( 'Q' 'X' ) ) ) 
EVAL
x: -75
0: 37777777665
0x: ffffffb5
tag(x): 1
val(x): -19
car(x): 0
cdr(x): 0
'A'
```

Comment: Regarding the formatting, will this be an [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org) entry? ;-)

Comment: The first line of code reads: `http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.c`

Comment: @devnull Ah, missed that; too early I think :-)

Comment: The formatting is a double-edged sword, to be sure. The upside is that the source itself does triple duty as a cheat-sheet, a full-reference-implementation, and a working prototype. The idea is a different sort of embeddable interpreter. Where instead of interfacing, you hack your extensions straight onto it.

Comment: If you going to use someone elses code, at least pick one that is readable and maintainable. You *do* know what the acronym IOCCC means?

Comment: Didn't `http://www.ioccc.org/1989/jar.2.hint` help?

Comment: This is all mine, but it borrows heavily from the cited sources. I confess I don't fully understand that J thing.

Comment: The code that processes quote seems correct. You need to debug to see if something else than `(cadr e)` gets done as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reader is wrong, and your printer is lying to you.

Hint: try reading a list with more than one element, like `(1 2 3 4 5)`.

The problem is that `rd` calls `append` with the *element* it just read as the second argument. (The fix is already there, commented out.) In the test case above, that just happens to be a list itself, so `append` works. But the datum you're actually passing to `eval` is actually

```
(Q . (A . (Q . X)))
```

when printed correctly, or

```
(Q A Q . X)
```

with the standard list abbreviation.

And so yes, `eval` returns `A`, which is the right answer, unless you want to check that there are no unexpected terms.

The bug in the printer is that for pairs you print the cdr as if it were an element. You should print a dot between the car and the cdr, or you should write a helper function `prnlst` that does the abbreviated list printing.

Comment: So for the reader, the element needs to be wrapped in a 1-element list, a single cons-cell. I think I got the printer working, too, mostly (there's an extra closing-paren sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Much belated, but I finally got the reader and printer functions to (appear to) work with the above code.

```
prn(x){atomp(x)?printf("'%c' ",val(x)+ALPHA):
    numberp(x)?printf("%d ",val(x)):
    objectp(x)?printf("OBJ %d ",val(x)):
    consp(x)?printf("( "),prn(car(x)),printf(". "),prn(cdr(x)),printf(") "):
    printf("NIL ");}

prnlst(x){
    x==NIL?0:
    !consp(x)?prn(x):
    printf("( "),prnrem(x);
}
prnrem(x){
    if(x==NIL)R;// printf(")0 ");
    if(car(x)!=NIL)
        prn(car(x));
    else
        R;// printf(") ");
    null(cdr(x))?
        printf(") "):
    !listp(cdr(x))?
        prn(cdr(x)),printf(") "):
    printf(" "),prnlst(car(cdr(x))),prnrem(cdr(cdr(x))),printf(") ");
}

#define LPAR '('
#define RPAR ')'
rd(char**p){int t,u,v,z;
    if(!(**p))R 0;
    if(**p==' ')R++(*p),rd(p);
    if(**p==RPAR)R++(*p),atom(RPAR);
    if(**p==LPAR){++(*p);
        z=NIL;
        u=rd(p);
        z=cons(u,NIL);
        while(u=rd(p),!eq(u,atom(RPAR)))
            u=cons(u,NIL),
            z=append(z,u);
        R z;}
    if(**p>='0'&&**p<='9')R++(*p),number(*((*p)-1)-'0');
    R++(*p),atom(*((*p)-1));}
```

And now that it appears to be working, I've made a project page for it on [github](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c).

Answer (score -1):

It does perfectly right:

The sub expression

```
(QUOTE(ATOM(QUOTE X)))
```

is

```
(ATOM 'X)
```

and

```
(eval (atom 'x))
```

is

```
'X
```

(true)