# Preprocessor for_each witin SWIG interface

Tags: swig, c-preprocessor

I've been using the `REFLECTABLE` macro from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748131/168175) in my C++ header file, which looks like:

```c
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

// From the linked question, but (deliberately) ignored by SWIG here, 
// only relevant is as much as it defines REFLECTABLE for other preprocessors
#include "reflection.hh"

struct Timer {
  REFLECTABLE (
    (float) startTime,
    (float) endTime,
  )
};

#endif
```

The SWIG preprocessor doesn't follow `#include` and doesn't handle the definition of REFLECTABLE from the linked question anyway, so my plan is to ignore that entirely and replace it with a more appropriate SWIG specific definition of REFLECTABLE.

My goal is for the [SWIG preprocessor](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Preprocessor.html#Preprocessor_nn7) to expand Timer as though there was nothing special going on, i.e.:

```c
struct Timer {
  float startTime;
  float endTime;
};
```

To that end I have written a simple reflection.i that makes a recursive call to a `%define` SWIG macro:

```c
#define REM(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PAIR(x) REM x

%define EXPAND(tail, ...)
  PAIR(tail);
  EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

#define REFLECTABLE(...) EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__)
```

That I can use in test.i:

```c
%module test

%include "reflection.i"
%include "timer.h"
```

When we run `swig -python -Wall -E test.i` to inspect the result of running this through the SWIG preprocessor it almost works, but the definition at the end of recursion doesn't quite match what I'd like:

```c
struct Timer {
  /*@SWIG:reflection.i,4,EXPAND@*/
  float startTime;
  /*@SWIG:reflection.i,4,EXPAND@*/
  float endTime;
  EXPAND
};
```

The problem is that recursion gets terminated by the bareword `EXPAND` when `___VA_ARGS__` is empty. I looked at using map.h from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459454/168175), but that also doesn't work with the SWIG preprocessor.

How can I modify my definition of `REFLECTABLE` so that the SWIG preprocessor just generates the flat structure I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution in the end that required two changes:

1. There's more indirection to the recursion, we paste two tokens together to get the token `EXPAND_STOP` or `EXPAND_MORE`, depending on whether or not the `__VA_ARGS__` is empty during this evaluation. This selection takes place because SWIG evaluates

   ```
   #define STOP(...) MORE
   ```

   as `MORE` when there are arguments, but simply as STOP when there are no arguments.

   The `TOKEN` macro then adds the required indirection for the token paste operator to work.
2. There's a fake first argument to both `EXPAND_MORE` and `EXPAND_STOP` that prevents the same behaviour from stopping us eating the call to `EXPAND_STOP` with no arguments.

```c
#define REM(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PAIR(x) REM x

#define TOKEN_(x,y) x##y
#define TOKEN(x,y) TOKEN_(x, y)

#define STOP(...) MORE

%define EXPAND_MORE(fake, ...)
  EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

#define EXPAND_STOP(fake, ...)

%define EXPAND(tail, ...)
  PAIR(tail);
  TOKEN(EXPAND_,  STOP(__VA_ARGS__)) ## (fake, ##__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

#define REFLECTABLE(...) EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Although possibly not the most elegant solution this is tested and working with SWIG 3.0.2.