# Count number of variadic arguments in macro function

Tags: c++, c, macros

Here are two lines I saw in OpenCV

```
#define CV_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...)    N
#define CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(...)      CV_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

I guess it is to count the number of variadic  arguments passing to `CV_VA_NUM_ARGS`. Take following code for example:

```
CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(a,b,c)
```

will be extended to

```
CV_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(a,b,c,10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

At this point, I am stuck on understanding what is going on. Concretely, **I don't know the utility of `_1`,`_2`,etc.** Can anyone help me out? Here is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317474/macro-to-count-number-of-arguments) while more complex to me.

**EDIT:**
When I pass no arguments(say `CV_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER()`), the macro will be replaced by 1 instead of 0, why is that?

Comment: BTW, if you want to count the number of variadic arguments for more than 10, `#define CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(...) std::tuple_size<decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>::value` works in C++11.

Comment: @Hiroki: generally, it is done to dispatch on other MACRO depending of argument count, so this way "fail"

Comment: @Jarod42 thx but I still do not well understand your comment. Assuming [such use cases](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q9PZAyprPPPE3QWd), I commented on the above line. So what does your “fail” mean? Since I know that you are a great C++ programmer through my this 2 months SO life, I want to understand precisely what you are saying with examples and learn from you :).

Comment: @Hiroki: I meant iterate over variadic MACRO as for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194701/2684539),

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah I see. many thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_1` to `_10` are just placeholders from the start in order to make sure `N` is positioned over the correct number from `10` to `0` (depending on `__VA_ARGS__`). They serve no purpose other than occupying a position.

Since each macro parameter must have a distinct identifier, those identifiers are as good as any.

---

Regarding your edit, that is limitation of the preprocessor. An empty token sequence is a valid argument to a macro. So it really is a single argument, because `__VA_ARGS__ ,` (note the comma) becomes such an argument.

It's quite a known issue, so much so that C++20 added the [`__VA_OPT__`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0306r4.html) preprocessor macro. It allows to add the comma conditionally. On C++20, the implementation can be fixed to work as expected like this:

```
#define CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(...)      CV_VA_NUM_ARGS_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about `_1`, `_2` etc. You can have `i`, `j`, `k` in their place.

The value of N depends on the number of arguments you have passed because N becomes the 11th element in the macro expansion (because of the 10 place holders).

So for `CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(a,b,c)`, the 11th element is 3.
For `CV_VA_NUM_ARGS(a,b,c,d,e,f)`, the 11th element is 6 and so on.

Note that with this particular code you can count only up to 10 arguments. Using more than 10 arguments will generate a compiler error.