# Apply a macro to a variable argument list

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99, variadic-macros

I have a variadic macro and a regular macro. I use them like this:

```
LIST(
  ELEM(a),
  ELEM(b)
  // usually about 4-8 elements
)
```

I would like `LIST` to automatically invoke `ELEM` on each argument so that I can write `LIST(a, b)` instead of `LIST(ELEM(a), ELEM(b))`

How can I achieve this without using a preprocessing library? A detailed explanation or a link to one would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the [map macro](https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro) as described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707148/foreach-macro-on-macros-arguments) would fit your needs. if yes i would mark this as a duplicate of the other question. also *just personally* i would probably not do this in C, as i am not such an adventurous coder ;)

Comment: @ramrunner The MAP macro looks like it will do what I want