# Is there any generic way of computing max of N integer constants (MACROS) at compile time -

Tags: c, embedded

I need to compute max of N integer constants (MACROS) at **compile time**.

This is a possible way out -

```
#define C_MAX_2(a, b)                         (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define C_MAX_3(a, b, c)                      C_MAX_2((C_MAX_2((a),(b))), (c))
#define C_MAX_4(a, b, c, d)                   C_MAX_2((C_MAX_2((a),(b))), \
                                                      (C_MAX_2((c),(d))))
#define C_MAX_5(a, b, c, d, e)                C_MAX_2((C_MAX_3((a),(b), (c))), \
                                                      (C_MAX_2((d),(e))))
```

Any better generic way in C ?

Comment: Does this even work compile time?

Comment: Having a script to calculate constants and write source file would seem more sensible and flexible approach.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824639/variadic-recursive-preprocessor-macros-is-it-possible

Comment: @ Bart Friederichs, yes it works at compile time is all args to macros are constants.

Comment: @user694733, can you please provide me an example to such a script. It should parse header fies for provided constants and its values. Compute max, and the define a new constant with max value.

Comment: @ZEN.Kamath I usually have my data in in some generic format (CSV/TXT/JSON/XML/...), something that Python can easily read. Then I calculate data and finally open and write source files. Scripts are usually less than 100 lines, but you can do what ever you want them to.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should have these values calculated during compilation. Assuming of course that a, b ,c, d and e are all constants. This is basic constant propagation.

So, if this works as expected than that's the optimal way - during runtime there are not `max` calculations.

**Edit**
This is true for debug (non optimized) builds as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, @egur is right,

> during runtime there are not max calculations.

So you should'n worry about performance

A more consistent (generic) way could be

```
#define MAX_2(n1, n2) (n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2)
#define MAX_3(n1, n2, n3)         MAX_2(n1, MAX_2(n2, n3))
#define MAX_4(n1, n2, n3, n4)     MAX_2(n1, MAX_3(n2, n3, n4))
#define MAX_5(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) MAX_2(n1, MAX_4(n2, n3, n4, n5))
```

Comment: No I am not worried about performance, I am avaoiding dynamic memory allocation. I need to define an array with fixed size in compile time.

Comment: At least the MAX_2 macro might need to have an internal parenthesis at  `(n1) > (n2)`. Otherwise you can't call it like a function in some cases. For example `MAX_2(byte1 & mask, byte2 & mask)` would with the present code expand to `(byte1 & (mask > byte2) & mask)`.

Answer (score 0):

First we define a macro for counting how many arguments were passed.

```
#define COUNTARGS(...) GET21ST(__VA_ARGS__,COUNTDOWN())
#define COUNTDOWN() 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
#define GET21ST(a20,a19,a18,a17,a16,a15,a14,a13,a12,a11,a10,a9,a8,a7,a6,a5,a4,a3,a2,a1,a,...) a
```

However the expansion of `GET21ST` will happen before `COUNTDOWN`, so we need to force the precompiler to evaluate these in a different order. Fortunately [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/4499969) provides us with a mechinism to do just that.

```
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL1(EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL3(EVAL3(EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL5(EVAL5(EVAL5(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL5(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define VANISH()
#define OBSTRUCT(...) __VA_ARGS__ VANISH()
#define COUNTDOWN() 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
#define COUNTARGS(...) EVAL(OBSTRUCT(GET21ST)(__VA_ARGS__,COUNTDOWN()))
#define GET21ST(a20,a19,a18,a17,a16,a15,a14,a13,a12,a11,a10,a9,a8,a7,a6,a5,a4,a3,a2,a1,a,...) a
```

Now we are able to automatically select the correct macro from a list based on the number of arguments.

Todo this we will need a collection of macros to select from.

```
#define MAX_1(n) n
#define MAX_2(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define MAX_3(a,...) MAX_2(a,MAX_2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define MAX_4(a,...) MAX_2(a,MAX_3(__VA_ARGS__))
...
#define MAX_20(a,...) MAX_2(a,MAX_19(__VA_ARGS__))
```

We will also need some way of generating new macro calls.

```
#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
```

From here we can define a generic `MAX` macro that will call the appropriate specific macro.

```
#define MAX(...) CAT(MAX_,COUNTARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And testing on https://godbolt.org/ with the `-E` flag.

This:

```
MAX(2,3,4,1)
```

Results in:

```
(2>(3>(4>1?4:1)?3:(4>1?4:1))?2:(3>(4>1?4:1)?3:(4>1?4:1)))
```

---

**NOTE**

For those using C++, this is a simpler and safer macro.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX(...) [](auto v)constexpr{      \
        return *std::max_element(v.begin(), \
                                v.end());    \
    }(std::vector<float>{__VA_ARGS__})
```

Or even better, just use `algorithm` yourself.