# How do I configure microcontroller registers with no linter messages (embedded C)

Tags: c, embedded, cpu-registers, pic32

I like writing embedded C firmware to the [BARR-C:2018](https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/books/embedded-c-coding-standard) standard and I have recently started using PC-Lint to check the code.  I am currently using a PIC32 processor and I want to configure a register such that it:

1. is easy to read,
2. generates no linter messages,
3. compiles to a small amount of assembler.

I will outline my options below, with pros and cons. I am interested to hear your
solutions.  The register I have chosen to illustrate the problem is not important.

**Bit-fields with Microchip-supplied header**

✓ No lint messages, easy to read, easy to change individual settings

✗ 20 assembly instructions (O0) (increases in more complex registers)

```
ADC0TIMEbits.SAMC   = 25U;
ADC0TIMEbits.ADCDIV = 50U;
ADC0TIMEbits.BCHEN  = 0U;
ADC0TIMEbits.SELRES = 2U;
ADC0TIMEbits.ADCEIS = 6U;
```

**Simple assignment**

✓ No lint messages, 2 assembly instructions (O0)

✗ Not easy to read, not easy to change individual settings

```
ADC0TIME = 0x1A190019U;
```

**Explicitly consider every bit in every register**

✓ No lint messages, 2 assembly instructions (O0), easy to change individual settings

✗ Not easy to verify that the shift values are correct

```
ADC0TIME = ((25U << 0U) |     /* ADC0 Sample Time bits */
            (50U << 16U) |    /* ADC0 Clock Divisor bits */
            (0U  << 23U) |    /* Buffer Channel Enable bit */
            (2U  << 24U) |    /* ADC0 Resolution Select bits */
            (6U  << 26U));    /* ADC0 Early Interrupt Select bits */
```

**Explicitly consider every bit in every register using definitions from Microchip's supplied header file**

✓ 2 assembly instructions (O0), easy to change individual settings, shift values are controlled by manufacturer and are human-readable

✗ Values in the supplied header are signed, which lead to Lint info 8524: combining signed and unsigned types with operator '<<' [BARR-C:2018 Rule 5.3c]

```
ADC0TIME = ((25U << _ADC0TIME_SAMC_POSITION) |      /* ADC0 Sample Time bits */
            (50U << _ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_POSITION) |    /* ADC0 Clock Divisor bits */
            (0U  << _ADC0TIME_BCHEN_POSITION) |     /* Buffer Channel Enable bit */
            (2U  << _ADC0TIME_SELRES_POSITION) |    /* ADC0 Resolution Select bits */
            (6U  << _ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_POSITION));    /* ADC0 Early Interrupt Select bits */
```

**As above + casting the constants to get rid of the linter message**

✓ 2 assembly instructions (O0), easy to change individual settings, shift values are controlled by manufacturer and are human-readable, no lint messages

✗ Casting looks cumbersome

```
ADC0TIME = ((25U << (uint32_t)_ADC0TIME_SAMC_POSITION) |      /* ADC0 Sample Time bits */
            (50U << (uint32_t)_ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_POSITION) |    /* ADC0 Clock Divisor bits */
            (0U  << (uint32_t)_ADC0TIME_BCHEN_POSITION) |     /* Buffer Channel Enable bit */
            (2U  << (uint32_t)_ADC0TIME_SELRES_POSITION) |    /* ADC0 Resolution Select bits */
            (6U  << (uint32_t)_ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_POSITION));    /* ADC0 Early Interrupt Select bits */
```

Alternatively, I could modify the Microchip-supplied header and define the constants as unsigned.  That means the header is non-standard and I need to include it in my project repository.  Is that a problem?

Edit:
Extract from Microchip header file.  Values are signed:

```
#define _ADC0TIME_SAMC_POSITION                  0x00000000
#define _ADC0TIME_SAMC_MASK                      0x000003FF
#define _ADC0TIME_SAMC_LENGTH                    0x0000000A

#define _ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_POSITION                0x00000010
#define _ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_MASK                    0x007F0000
#define _ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_LENGTH                  0x00000007

#define _ADC0TIME_BCHEN_POSITION                 0x00000017
#define _ADC0TIME_BCHEN_MASK                     0x00800000
#define _ADC0TIME_BCHEN_LENGTH                   0x00000001

#define _ADC0TIME_SELRES_POSITION                0x00000018
#define _ADC0TIME_SELRES_MASK                    0x03000000
#define _ADC0TIME_SELRES_LENGTH                  0x00000002

#define _ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_POSITION                0x0000001A
#define _ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_MASK                    0x1C000000
#define _ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_LENGTH                  0x00000003
```

Comment: `#define U (uint32_t)` `.... ( 6U  << U _ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_POSITION ) \n           (` ?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That joke was not funny.

Comment: Or you could use `-O1` ? Or you could write a macro that uses `__VA_ARGS__` and creates a single statement.

Comment: @Lundin Do you have a better idea? I think the last version is the best and good enough. If it is too long for you, you can use a macro to make it a tiny bit shorter (but not a lot).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The better idea would be to use constants that are already unsigned 32, since that's the only thing that actually makes sense on a 32 bit MCU. It seems strange to me that Microchip wouldn't be aware that their PIC32 is a 32 bitter, so alternatively maybe stop using broken static analysers/hallucinators like PC Lint.

Comment: @Lundin Agree that they should be `unsigned`, but we can't change that.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I library implementer who made them signed clearly cannot be trusted to produce basic embedded systems source code and so the solution is to not use that library...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure microcontroller registers with no linter messages

Use the option `As above + casting the constants to get rid of the linter message`.

Comment: Why would there be a need to cast in the first place? That doesn't make any sense. The OP should strive to be an actual engineer and question this warning message, rather than blindly accepting it.

Comment: @Lundin The values in Microchip's header are signed.  The linter informs me that I am left-shifting with a signed number

Comment: @LightBlue I would strongly recommend to get a better tool chain. This library seems to be of poor quality and that PC Lint is of very poor quality has been known forever.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of assembler instructions under `O0` is irrelevant. However, since these are hardware peripheral registers and `volatile`-qualified, the optimizer can only do so much about the code when enabled.

> Bit-fields with Microchip-supplied header

As-is, this is definitely the wrong solution to any problem, because you will end up writing to the same register multiple times. And bit-fields are problematic for numerous other reasons too. You could only use this in a sensible way if storing all results into a temporary, non-`volatile` variable in RAM and then copy it into the actual register with a single assignment.

> `ADC0TIME = 0x1A190019U;`

This is an unreadable mess of "magic numbers" and therefore obviously it should be avoided like the plague.

> Explicitly consider every bit in every register

This is a bit better but you are still using "magic numbers".

> Explicitly consider every bit in every register using definitions from Microchip's supplied header file

This is close to the "de facto" standard way of using hardware registers. It is quite readable but the left operands of the shifts should be named constants or at least explained with comments.

> As above + casting the constants to get rid of the linter message

This is kind of nonsense. In case the provided Microchip constants are of a small integer type, then they would get implicitly integer promoted to `int` which I take it is 32 bits on your MCU.

I don't know the Michael Barr standard, but it's basically a light version of MISRA C and in MISRA C, you aren't allowed to have implicit integer promotions. And MISRA C isn't specific enough as to make an exception to the right operand of shifts.

Because the right operand of shifts is harmless. It *is* integer promoted but otherwise does not affect the end result at all. The result of shifts is always of the type of the (promoted) *left* operand.

Please note that all MISRA/Barr concerns about shifts are mainly focused on using a signed left operand, which is pretty much always wrong. Or more far-fetched, maybe a negative right operand which would be senseless.

---

What you *should* do:

Use the "using definitions from Microchip's supplied header file" version but if possible with even less magic numbers.

On a 32-bit MCU then use 32 bit unsigned constants. If the constants provided by Microchip aren't unsigned 32, then their library is broken. If they are but your linter is whining about them still, then your linter is broken.

There may be commercial compilers with register support for this particular MCU, which could be an option in case the Microchip libraries are broken. Otherwise rolling out your own register map isn't *that* hard, I've done this on several occasions by parsing the text from the pdf manual and translated it to C source.

Misc tips & tricks can be found here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: Disagree with: "The amount of assembler instructions under O0 is irrelevant." Of course they are. I want somewhat reproducible code being generated that works, regardless of optimization. This is why i don't use a optimizer, if possible, and check if the generated code is fast and short enough.

Comment: I can modify the existing Microchip header and append 'U' to the definitions.  This works nicely.  My concern is that I now have a non-standard header, so I would need to include it in my project.  Is that an acceptable thing to do?

Comment: @LightBlue General best practices is to always include such libs as a local copy in your project anyway. Otherwise you are subject to any whims and bugs that the tool vendor can come up with at any time. Plus problems with managing builds when half the source sits at some local path to an IDE.

Comment: @Lundin I made a copy of the supplied header in my project and the header has more problems than just signed values.  The compiler reported hundreds of "warning: ISO C99 doesn't support unnamed structs/unions [-Wpedantic]".  Would you recommend (a) going through and fixing all the warnings, (b) stripping out everything I don't need to create a minimalist header and fixing what's left, or (c) something else?

I appreciate that my choice of compiler and linter are not great, but given the tools I have to work with, I would like to create the best code I can.

Comment: @LightBlue Compile as standard C (C17) or the previous standard C11.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution. But when the last statement is too long for you, you can create a complicated network of macros to make that statement automatically.

Consider this monster (stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048661/6082851):

```
//Multiple macros to create a single statement to set a SFR
//v is the name of the SFT, a the Position in the register and b the value to set
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b)  ( (b) << (uint32_t) ( _ ## v ## _ ## a ## _POSITION )  ) 

#define CREATE_STATEMENT_2(v,a,b,c,d) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,c,d)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_3(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_2(v,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_4(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_3(v,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_5(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_4(v,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_6(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_5(v,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_7(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_6(v,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_8(v,a,b,...) CREATE_STATEMENT_1(v,a,b) | CREATE_STATEMENT_7(v,__VA_ARGS__)


//MACRO_SELECTOR(...) evaluates to the literal number of the passed-in arguments divided by 2 
//(because we need 2 parameters per macro).
#define MACRO_SELECTOR_N1(X,_8,_8_1,_7,_7_1,_6,_6_1,_5,_5_1,_4,_4_1,_3,_3_1,_2,_2_1,_1,_1_1,N,...) N
#define MACRO_SELECTOR(...) MACRO_SELECTOR_N1(0, __VA_ARGS__ ,8,9,7,7,6,6,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0)

#define CREATE_STATEMENT_N2(V,N,...)  CREATE_STATEMENT_ ## N(V,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CREATE_STATEMENT_N1(V,N,...)  CREATE_STATEMENT_N2(V,N,__VA_ARGS__)
//Create a single statement to set a SFR.
//V is the name of the register, after that is a list of position in that register and after that,
// the value it should be set to.
#define CREATE_STATEMENT(V,...)       V=CREATE_STATEMENT_N1(V,MACRO_SELECTOR(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__);
```

If you put that in a header, you can use this shorter way to set a register:

```
CREATE_STATEMENT
  (
    ADC0TIME,
    SAMC,     25U,
    ADCDIV,   50U,
    BCHEN,     0U,
    SELRES,    2U,
    ADCEIS,    6U
  );
```

This will result in

```
ADC0TIME=( (25U) << (uint32_t) (_ADC0TIME_SAMC_POSITION) ) | ( (50U) << (uint32_t) (_ADC0TIME_ADCDIV_POSITION) ) | ( (0U) << (uint32_t) (_ADC0TIME_BCHEN_POSITION) ) | ( (2U) << (uint32_t) (_ADC0TIME_SELRES_POSITION) ) | ( (6U) << (uint32_t) (_ADC0TIME_ADCEIS_POSITION) );
```

EDIT: Add `_<registername>_` and `_POSITION` automatically.

Comment: And now just a tiny detail: how to make these macros MISRA compliant...